# Aliasing a variable for later use are overwritten when changing the field

Tags: cypress

In the migration to Cypress 12 it says that the aliases are adapted according to the dom, I know. But I did not expect this:
In my case, I have a field with a first value. I put this value into an Alias for later use. Into the same field I write now something else. Later, I want to restore the field again to the previous value (stored as alias). But in this alias is the new value and not the previous one:

This is how I store the fist value:

```
function aliasAliasNameValue() {
  cy.get(`div[data-textfield="editField"] input`)
    .invoke('attr', 'value').as('ALIASNAME')
    .then((attVal) => {
      cy.log(attVal as string);
    });
}
```

This is how I get the first value:

```
function restoreAliasField() {
  cy.get('@ALIASNAME').then((aliasN) => {
    cy.get(`div[data-textfield="editField"] input`)
      .clear()
      .type(aliasN as unknown as string);
  });
}
```

Here is a description of the test:

```
it('Change field and restore it.', () => {
 // do something....
 ...
 aliasAliasNameValue();
 ...
 // change the field save and come back
  
 restoreAliasField(); // but it is not restored: it writes the new value!!
 ...
});
```

How can I get the first value back?

Answer (score 0):

I think this line is not working `.type(aliasN as unknown as string)`.

It looks like you are trying to define the type, but you should just try with `.type(aliasN)` and see it that improves things for you.

Comment: Sorry no. This is done so that the ES lint does not complain and does not do anything with the value of the variable.

Comment: Actually this is a bug (or a use case, which they forgot):[https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/25173](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/25173). I can't believe they would ignore such a case!

Answer (score 0):

As of version 12.4.0 you can use it again. Although it is necessary to add an additional parameter:

```
.as('ALIASNAME', { type: 'static' }
```

type: 'query' would update the variable...